# How to watch lots of wallet addresses for new bitcoin transactions?

Tags: bitcoind

I need to watch many wallet addresses for new bitcoin transactions as they enter new blocks. I also need this transaction data to make updates on my end

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple strategies I've used:

**Run a bitcoin node:** bitcoind has a `-blocknotify` flag you can run that will allow you to execute a command with each new block. You can then use JSON-RPC to query your node for all transactions/addresses in the block. It will take a bit of work to set this up, but it will work

**Use a service:** I've used https://www.blockcypher.com/ which works well, but it can be pricey. https://blockchainwebhooks.com is much more affordable, but not as many features.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

If you want an android app to watch the balance of addresses, you can use Sentinal.  It's created by the Samourai wallet guys, it's awesome.